# Python __str__() creating error

Tags: python, list, runtime-error

here's the code

```
from robustCard import Card
import random

class Hand:
    def __init__(self,numCardsInHand):
        self.hand = list()
        for x in range(0,numCardsInHand):
            randVal = random.randint(1,13)
            randKey = random.choice(['d','c','h','s'])
            self.hand.append(Card(randVal,randKey))

    def bjValue(self):
        totalVal = 0
        for x in range(0,len(self.hand)):
           totalVal+=self.hand[x].bjValue()
        return totalVal

    def __str__(self):
        for x in range(0,len(self.hand)):
            print(self.hand[x])        

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    hand  = Hand(5)
    print(hand)
```

here's my card classes **str**():

```
 def __str__(self):
    letterRank = self.rankList[self.rank-1]
    letterSuit = self.suitDict[self.suit]
    return "%s of %s" % (letterRank,letterSuit)
```

Here's my error:

```
Four of clubs
Jack of clubs
nine of diamonds
Queen of clubs
Seven of clubs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bmassoumi/Documents/Web development/python_workspace/Python class/Hand.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(hand)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

How do I output the list of cards in the hand list when i have two different **str()**'s to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Your `__str__` method *must* must return a value.  It doesn't (it just prints).

You could do something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(str(card) for card in self.hand)
```

Comment: There's no need for the explicit loop or the extra list, and you do need to call `str` on the items in `self.hand` (which are `Card` instances). I'd do `"\n".join(map(str, self.hand))` (though you could use a generator expression rather than `map`).

Comment: @Blckknght:  Thanks.  Posted without really thinking too hard (or testing).